# Where is a portable app running from when the usb stick is pulled out without closing that app?

Tags: usb, portable-apps

Where is a portable app running from when the usb stick is pulled out without closing that app?

Is it in memory?
Is it written the on hard disk as temporary files (where exactly is it, appdata or where)?

Does that mean another user could gain access just clicking that from the system tray and saving to other folders?

How about when the system crashes and the portable app is not closed the normal way? On the next open, will it stay somewhere on temporary folders?

Comment: Its in memory, any temporary file creation would fail, depending on the behavior of the portal application itself.

Comment: @ Ramhound : Thanks. I think u are referring to only "When the System Crashed", right? How about "USB Pulled Out Without Closing"? Also, what is the most that the next user (lets say an adversary) could get from the files that I had left behind there?

Comment: I have no idea what your asking.  A portable application normally would write files to the save drive it was launched from.  Don't remove the drive until you close the application if you don't want informatin spiliage.

Answer (score 4):

When you open a file on a removable disk, this file is cached in RAM along with the executable. Removing the USB drive forcefully (i.e, without ejecting) will cause any subsequent reads/writes to the drive to fail, often resulting in the affected program crashing.

However, if this doesn't happen the application will remain running since it's stored in RAM. *In most cases*, the computer crashing or restarting will leave no traces of this portable application *unless* the application copies itself someplace (like a temporary directory) when it runs. This is entirely dependent on the program though.

Comment: @ Nathan C : Yes, my portable apps don't copies files outside of the install folder. My concern is I pulled my USB and I'm not sure if I had closed it or not, probably not. What is the most that the next user of the pc could get? My portable app is Keynote (notes/todo/organizer software).

Comment: I'm not sure because it depends on how the app works. Most of the time, attempting to open anything will cause it to crash and they'll get nothing since it can't read its database file.